# Find the solution of this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the function y solution of 
$$(x+1)(x^2+1)y'=2x^2+x$$

Initial conditions : $y = 1$ when $x=0 $ 
I tried to simplify the equation first by breaking down the fraction in two sides. so that I will find the primitive of both side then find y. But my problem is the second part $(3x-1)/(2x^2+2)$. I cannot find its primitive.

Comment: Thank you. There is no θ, it was an error. y is a function which contain x and maybe a constant

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Could you maybe provide some context to your question especially what is $l$. Furthermore questions of the type "Here is my task. Solve it for me" are poorly received here. So show what you have done so far. Where do you struggle and so on :)

Comment: This DE is separable.

Comment: Alright. I'm new here in fact. So here is a differential equation of first order. I struggle to find y (the solution of the equation). I tried to simplify it first by breaking down the fraction in two sides. so that I will find the primitive of both side. My problem is the second part (x-1)/(2x^2+2). I cannot find its primitive

Comment: @AsmaDieng Ah okay. So you are struggeling with solving the occuring integral. That is something important to know. But again I am asking you : What is $l$ ^^ Since I cannot help you solving this equation without knowing what this maybe constant is.

Comment: Oh it's not l but 1. I really don't know why it looks like a l here

Comment: Ah. Okay. Then everything is clear right now.

Comment: Great then. So should I change my approach ? I literally tried everything since yesterday. This is my last idea. I'm so frustated, it is just an equation of first order and I can't find it

Comment: No. Your attempt was right but you made a mistake somewhere between but I cannot figure out where exactly you went wrong.

Comment: If you’d like someone to tell you where you’re going wrong, you should show more of your work.

Comment: Integrate by partial fractions: $\dfrac{x(2x+1)}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}$

Comment: I had problems to write what I've done so far because I'm not really familiar with coding. The second part was actually (3x-1)/(2x^2+2). I forgot the 3 yesterday by typing. Sorry sorry sorry, this is so new for me..

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help.I should just separate (3x-1)/(2x^2+2) by (3x)/(2x^2+2) - 1/(2x^2+2). And it would be easier to find the anti-derivatives. Thanks again people !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Adrian Kleister mentioned within the comments and which was in fact your own attempt is to seperate the equation in the following way

$$\begin{align}
(x+1)(x^2+1)y′=2x^2+x\Leftrightarrow y′=\frac{2x^2+x}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}
\end{align}$$

Taking the integral leads to

$$y=\int \frac{2x^2+x}{(x+1)(x^2+1)} dx +c$$

where the integral can be solved by using the technique of partial decomposition. Therefore we write

$$\frac{2x^2+x}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}=\frac{A}{x+1}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+1}\Leftrightarrow2x^2+x=A(x^2+1)+(Bx+C)(x+1)$$

From hereon we get a system of equations for $A,B$ and $C$. Solving this system yields to $A=\frac12$, $B=\frac32$ and $C=-\frac12$ and so we have to integrate now

$$y=\int \frac{3x-1}{2(x^2+1)}+\frac{1}{2(x+1)} dx +c = \frac12\int \frac{3x}{x^2+1}-\frac{1}{x^2+1}+\frac{1}{x+1} dx +c$$

The solution to this can be obtained by using standard techniques based on the natural logarithm and the inverse tangens. So finally the anti-derivatives and so the function $y$ is given by

$$y=\frac12 \ln(x+1) + \frac34\ln(x^2+1) - \frac12\arctan(x) + c $$

Plugging in the IVP yields to

$$1=c$$

and therefore the solution is given by

$$y(x)=\frac12 \ln(x+1) + \frac34\ln(x^2+1) - \frac12\arctan(x) + 1 $$

Answer (score 2):

We have $y'=\frac{2x^2+x}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}$. Assuming $\frac{2x^2+x}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}=\frac{A}{x+1}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+1}$ for some $A,B,C \in \mathbb{R}$ and equating the coefficients of the respective powers of $x$, we'll get $A=\frac{1}{2}, B=\frac{3}{2}, C=-\frac{1}{2}$.

Therefore $y'=\frac{1}{2(x+1)}+\frac{3x}{2(x^2+1)}-\frac{1}{3(x^2+1)}$, which gives integrating both side, $$y=\frac{1}{2}\ln (x+1)+\frac{3}{4}\ln (x^2+1)-\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}x+a,\quad \text{ where } a \text { is an arbitrary constant.}$$

Now, as $y=1$ for $x=0$, so $a=1$ and thus
$$y=\frac{1}{2}\ln (x+1)+\frac{3}{4}\ln (x^2+1)-\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}x+1.$$